# Get simple Prolog example to work

Tags: prolog

I am trying to run a simple `gprolog` to run on my Linux machine, GNU Prolog was installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

From the [GNU Prolog Intro](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/12%20prolog_intro.pdf) I got the following example, stored in `HelloWorld.pl`.

```
parent(hank,ben).
parent(hank,denise).
parent(irene,ben).
parent(irene,denise).
parent(alice,carl).
parent(ben,carl).
parent(denise,frank).
parent(denise,gary).
parent(earl,frank).
parent(earl,gary).
grandparent(X,Z):-parent(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(Z,Y),ancestor(X,Z).
```

I start `gprolog`, enter `[HelloProlog].` and get the following error:

```
| ?- [HelloProlog].
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,consult/1)
```

Even if I do not load the code from a file but run it interactively I get an error:

```
uwe@z11:~/desktop$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?- parent(Luke,Anakin).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,parent/2),top_level/0)
| ?-
```

Is my installation broken or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The issue seems to be the filename. Storing the code in `family.pl` makes gprolog process it, `HelloProlog` gives the error. Both files have the same content and are in the same directory.

Comment: @PauloMoura answer explains why. As he described, you can use "HelloProlog.pl" as your file name as long as you quote it, `'HelloProlog'` or `'HelloProlog.pl'` so it remains an atom in Prolog. Strings that start with uppercase without quoting in Prolog are variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Prolog, variables start with an upper case letter (or with an underscore), hence the instantiation error you got with the goal `[HelloProlog]`. Simply use instead `['HelloProlog']`. I.e. represent the file path as a Prolog atom, which require single quotes when they start with an upper case letter.

The existence error you got is simply due to querying a predicate that it's not defined. You need to load the `HelloWorld.pl` file first.